# Removing Tab from TabHost Giving me run time Exception (NullPointerException)

Tags: android

When i wanted to remove the Tab from Tab Host   some time it works perfectly but some time it's giving me NullPointerException i didn't get any solution for it i read many solutions but nothing works perfectly for me.

**Here's my code. What is the error in the Code and How can i fix this ?**

This is the Code Inside Listener of TabHost

```
int selected_Tab=0; is an Instance Variable
tabHost_For_Excercise.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selected_Tab=tabHost_For_Excercise.getCurrentTab();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Current Tab"+ selected_Tab, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });



//I Created tabs Dynamically when the Add Action bar button is clicked


case R.id.action_add:
final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(ExcerciseActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_of_add_tab);
 final EditText et_Name_Of_Tab=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_Name_Of_Tab);
 final Button btn_Submit=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_submit_Name);
  btn_Submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String tab_Name = et_Name_Of_Tab.getText().toString();
        tabSpec=tabHost_For_Excercise.newTabSpec("tag1");
    listOfExcercise=new ArrayList<String>();
     listOfExcercise.add("DDD");
     listOfExcercise.add("TTT");
     listOfExcercise.add("VVVV");
     listOfExcercise.add("LLL");
     createTab(tabSpec, listOfExcercise);

     tabSpec.setIndicator(tab_Name);
     tabHost_For_Excercise.addTab(tabSpec);
      dialog.dismiss();
    }   

});
dialog.show();
```

this is the code when remove btn is clicked

```
 try{
tabHost_For_Excercise.setCurrentTab(selected_Tab);  

 tabHost_For_Excercise.getTabWidget()
      .removeView(tabHost_For_Excercise.getTabWidget().getChi ldTabViewAt(selected_Tab));
}catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
}
```

This is My Log Cat

```
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086): at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2500)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at  
android.widget.TabWidget.dispatchDraw(TabWidget.java:323)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at 
android.view.View.draw(View.java:11187)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2892)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2494)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2890)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2494)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2890)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2494)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2890)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2494)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11187)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2892)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2494)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2890)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2494)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11187)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2210)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1816)
 04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2628)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
 04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
 04-07 17:09:01.877: E/AndroidRuntime(30086):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer very early but sorry for posting it so late

i just save each **TabSpec** in **ArrayList list** and after that i just remove all    View form Table Layout
  tLayout.clearAllView();
  and remove from **list.remove(position)** as well.

and than add the tabSpec from start to last using ArrayList

```
    for(int i=0;i<tabSpec.size();i++){
        tLayout.addTabSpec(tabSpec.get(i));
   }
```

Comment: Isn't there a better solution in newer android versions?? Anyway I could not find but only answers like this.